# How to use threadpool class in .net compact framework with c#?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I am looking for the solution for multi threading in c# .net compact framework. though threadpool class is good solution but is there any way to sync them like WaitHandle.WaitAll in compact framework?

Comment: guys i have got solution for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem.  The [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) works just like on the desktop.  For thread synchronization objects, you have all of the usual suspects from the [System.Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.aspx) namespace.  Admittedly, the CF omits a few nice-to-have methods (like WaitAll), but those can either be worked around (multiple waits in succession), you can P/Invoke the Create/Wait APIs or you can use the [Smart Device Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/cf/products/sdf.ocf), which has all of the sync objects fully implemented.

Comment: hi,
thanks for the nice link. But i solved the problem using .net CF's WaitOne() method and using an AutoResetEvent object which is set when all the threads are reached to their completion.