# Ensuring background threads complete on process exit in .Net Compact Framework 3.5 dll

Tags: .net, multithreading, compact-framework

I have a dll that has a static method that clients call to log some information to various destinations. This method uses the ThreadPool to start the logging work on another thread. I need a way to reliably ensure these threads complete before the process exits. The AppDomains' ProcessExit event is not available in the 3.5 CF, so where/how could I reliably wait for these threads to finish? The only solution I can think of is to make the threads foreground threads (the work on the threads is small and finite), but it has been suggested in other SO answers that this is bad form ( but without qualification so not sure why).

Comment: WaitHandle.WaitAll() doesn't appear to be available either.  You could just change it, use Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = false; in your thread method.  If that's the "bad form" you are talking about then you'll have to avoid losing track of your threads so you can use WaitOne() or Join().  That's another kind of "bad form", the unpractical kind.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hans, there's very limited support for synchronisation primitives in 3.5 CF. If I'm using foreground threads then I wouldn't need to Join the threads since they'll keep the app alive until they finish

Comment: Do you really need to have a bunch of background threads?  If the work they do is `small and finite` then have a single persistent thread that executes the logging tasks from a work queue.

Comment: @tcarvin thanks for your response. I'd still need to ensure that one thread finishes if the app exits. When you say "persistent" thread, are you talking about a foreground thread?

Comment: see other questions at stackoverflow like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552813/how-to-use-threadpool-class-in-net-compact-framework-with-c-sharp-c-sharp

Comment: Yes, a single foreground thread that you dispatch all the small items of work to.  You would keep a reference to it, and could Thread.Join on it at shutdown to wait for it to complete.

Comment: @josef Thanks for your reply, but its not the "how" to wait for a thread to finish that I need, its the "when".

Comment: @tcarvin "...and could Thread.Join on it at shutdown" ...but that's the issue, since there is no ProcessExit event in the 3.5CF, where could I wait for the thread to complete. And even if there were a Process.Exit event this scenario, with a single foreground thread, would make it tricky since the thread would need to constantly monitor the work item queue - there's no natural endpoint for the thread. As far as I can see the only difference between a background and foreground thread is that the latter keeps the process alive, so I think multiple foreground threads is the way to go.

Comment: If you are authoring a library that requires cleanup, it is the calling code that is responsible to call the Close and Dispose methods.  If they don't, that is a bug in their code.  *That* is where you hook in to do a Thread.Join...in the method they call to clean-up.    If they don't call it, it is on them.  Launching a bunch of untracked foreground threads on a low powered CE device doesn't sound like a good idea in most circumstances.

Comment: I would either use a number of threads managed by myself or use WaitCallback(threadproc, state) and give every thread in the thread pool an unique state object (ie a counter). The threadproc(s) can then call an event with the given state object and you can manage a list of finished threads (using the counters provided).

Answer (score 0):

As said, use the state object to have a reference for every thread started in the threadpool. Use an event handler to signal the main process, which thread has terminated.

Here is a simple example using console code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadPoolTest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static int intRest=256;
        static object lockObject=new object();
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            bool bStop=false;
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
            work w=new work();
            //start about 256 threads using ThreadPool
            w.start();
            w.CounterReached+=count;
            do{
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                lock(lockObject){
                    if(intRest==0)
                        bStop=true;
                }
            }while(!bStop);
            Console.WriteLine ("### Hello World END ###");
        }

        static void count(object sender, work.CounterEventArgs e){
            lock(lockObject){
                intRest--; //count down instead of checking which thread has terminated
            }
            Console.WriteLine("got event for " + e.counter.ToString());
        }
    }
    class work{

        public class CounterEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public int counter { get; set; }
            public CounterEventArgs(int i){
                counter=i;
            }
        }
        protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(CounterEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<CounterEventArgs> handler = CounterReached;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler<CounterEventArgs> CounterReached;

        void threadStart(object o){
            int i = (int)o;
            System.Console.WriteLine("Thread: "+i.ToString()+" started");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Thread: "+i.ToString()+" ended");
            OnThresholdReached(new CounterEventArgs(i));
        }


        public void start(){
            for(int i=0; i<256; i++){
                WaitCallback w=new WaitCallback(threadStart);
                System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(w, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I start new threads until 256 threads are reached. Each Waitcallback gets the number of the thread started. The main process/thread waits inside a while loop (console app) until all threads are finished.